# How do you configure your settings.py file to upload files to Amazon S3 database instead of local folders?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, settings

I have an issue with a Django/Python project currently where I can't seem to upload pictures to the amazon s3 database I have set up when making a new recipe for my cookbook app. The recipe will be created, however the picture file does not send to the S3 db and instead is sent to a local folder in my app folder instead. Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name='title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    serving_size = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    prep_time = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    cook_time = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    ingredients = models.TextField(blank=True)
    directions = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

```
class AddRecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['id', 'author']
```

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<secret key here>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<heroku app url here>', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ycb',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_filters',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    #'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ycb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ycb.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

#S3 BUCKETS CONFIG

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<access key id here>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<secret access key here>'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<aws storage bucket name here>'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/mediafiles/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)
```

Comment: You need to configure the DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE setting: `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`

Comment: All the files will need to be migrated to S3 and all DB entries will need to be updated to the correct values

Comment: I have done the above and re-ran my server and two things I notice:

1. Immediately, the existing recipes in my website, which had been displaying pictures, now show dead thumbnails. Inspecting the element I see the following:

<img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://<website name>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/Creole_Chicken__Rice.jpg">

When checking the database, I see that the files are all located inside Amazon S3. One thing that does seem weird is that it is looking toward a static folder I had created. Should these not go to a media files folder instead from media_url?

Comment: 2. When creating a new recipe, I do see that the file is uploaded to Amazon S3. However, the file gets sent to the static folder instead of a mediafiles folder which I had created. Do I need to add a media root variable to have files send over to the mediafiles folder?

Comment: For no. 1: If this is live data that you cannot delete then you will have to migrate the data to S3, is it live data? No. 2: this can be achieved by creating a custom storage class. I can provide an answer for 2 and hope 1 is false as you will have to write a potentially complicated script

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).